# Display table with different cell width in different rows

Tags: html, css

How i can adjust this misalignment with "display:table" in different rows? I do this for equal height in every rows without jquery function.
The calc width and the negative margis is for the border spacing and border collapse

[image: misalignment]

The code:

```css
* {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Sans-Serif;
  outline: none;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 1);
}
/* LIMITAZIONE: Per evitare di fare comparire lo scorrimento orizzontale sono necessari margini dx/sx la cui somma è uguale/maggiore dei pixel aggiunti al width della tabella */

.tableswrapper {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 1%;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
.tableswrapper div.table {
  width: calc(100% + 40px);
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 20px 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  padding: 0;
}
.tableswrapper div.table:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div[class^='cellwidth'] {
  display: table-cell;
  empty-cells: hide;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div[class^='cellwidth']:first-child {} .tableswrapper div.table div.row div[class^='cellwidth']:last-child {} .tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth1 {
  width: 1%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth2 {
  width: 2%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth3 {
  width: 3%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth4 {
  width: 4%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth5 {
  width: 5%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth6 {
  width: 6%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth7 {
  width: 7%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth8 {
  width: 8%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth9 {
  width: 9%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth10 {
  width: 10%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth15 {
  width: 15%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth20 {
  width: 20%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth25 {
  width: 25%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth30 {
  width: 30%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth33 {
  width: 33.3333333333%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth35 {
  width: 35%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth40 {
  width: 40%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth45 {
  width: 45%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth50 {
  width: 50%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth55 {
  width: 55%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth60 {
  width: 60%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth65 {
  width: 65%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth66 {
  width: 66.6666666666%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth70 {
  width: 70%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth75 {
  width: 75%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth80 {
  width: 80%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth85 {
  width: 85%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth90 {
  width: 90%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth95 {
  width: 95%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div.cellwidth100 {
  width: 100%;
}
/* TRICK: abilitare se si desiderano larghezze di colonna uguali sulla riga*/

/*
  .tableswrapper div.table {table-layout:fixed;}
  .tableswrapper div.table div.row div[class^='cellwidth'] {min-width:1%;width:1%;max-width:1%;}
  */

/* LIMITAZIONE: Le colonne all'interno di ogni riga che hanno un'immagine di testata devono avere la stessa larghezza */

.tableswrapper div.table div.row div[class^='cellwidth'] div.headerimage {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div[class^='cellwidth'] div.headerimage img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.tableswrapper div.table div.row div[class^='cellwidth'] div.cellcontents {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
/*.tableswrapper div.table div.row div[class^='cellwidth'] div.headerimage + div.cellcontents {padding-top:20px;}*/

.tableswrapper div.table div.row div[class^='cellwidth'] div.cellcontents h1.celltitle {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: red;
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

  <div class="tableswrapper">

    <div class="table">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cellwidth100">
          <div class="cellcontents">
            <h1 class="celltitle">Cell title 100%</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="table">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cellwidth30">
          <div class="cellcontents">
            <h1 class="celltitle">Cell title 30%</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cellwidth70">
          <div class="cellcontents">
            <h1 class="celltitle">Cell title 70%</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="table">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cellwidth30">
          <div class="cellcontents">
            <h1 class="celltitle">Cell title 30%</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cellwidth40">
          <div class="cellcontents">
            <h1 class="celltitle">Cell title 40%</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cellwidth30">
          <div class="cellcontents">
            <h1 class="celltitle">Cell title 30%</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="table">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cellwidth100">
          <div class="cellcontents">
            <h1 class="celltitle">Cell title 100%</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="table">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cellwidth25">
          <div class="cellcontents">
            <h1 class="celltitle">Cell title 25%</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cellwidth50">
          <div class="cellcontents">
            <h1 class="celltitle">Cell title 25%</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cellwidth25">
          <div class="cellcontents">
            <h1 class="celltitle">Cell title 25%</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="table">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cellwidth25">
          <div class="cellcontents">
            <h1 class="celltitle">Cell title 25%</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cellwidth50">
          <div class="cellcontents">
            <h1 class="celltitle">Cell title 50%</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cellwidth25">
          <div class="cellcontents">
            <h1 class="celltitle">Cell title 25%</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="table">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cellwidth25">
          <div class="cellcontents">
            <h1 class="celltitle">Cell title 25%</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cellwidth25">
          <div class="cellcontents">
            <h1 class="celltitle">Cell title 25%</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cellwidth25">
          <div class="cellcontents">
            <h1 class="celltitle">Cell title 25%</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cellwidth25">
          <div class="cellcontents">
            <h1 class="celltitle">Cell title 25%</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If this is a table, why not use tables (<table>)?

Comment: For the responsive layout. Although I use the tables the misalignment exists

Comment: Have you tried using `table-layout: fixed` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `<table>` and the `colspan` attribute.

It works because:

- the table's width is explicitly declared as `100%`; and
- there is a row (for scale) at the bottom which contains 100 cells

Every other cell in the table may then declare its correct relative width using the `colspan` attribute.

```css
table {
width: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
font-family: trebuchet ms, arial, sans-serif;
}

td {
border:18px solid rgb(255,0,0);
padding: 0 12px;
}

tr.scale td {
border: none;
padding: 0;
}

h2 {
color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="100">
<h2>Cell title 100%</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="30">
<h2>Cell title 30%</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</td>

<td colspan="70">
<h2>Cell title 70%</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</td>  
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="30">
<h2>Cell title 30%</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</td>

<td colspan="40">
<h2>Cell title 40%</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</td> 

<td colspan="30">
<h2>Cell title 30%</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="100">
<h2>Cell title 100%</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</td>  
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="25">
<h2>Cell title 25%</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</td>

<td colspan="25">
<h2>Cell title 25%</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</td> 

<td colspan="25">
<h2>Cell title 25%</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</td> 

<td colspan="25">
<h2>Cell title 25%</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="25">
<h2>Cell title 25%</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</td>

<td colspan="50">
<h2>Cell title 50%</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</td> 

<td colspan="25">
<h2>Cell title 25%</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="25">
<h2>Cell title 25%</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</td>

<td colspan="25">
<h2>Cell title 25%</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</td> 

<td colspan="25">
<h2>Cell title 25%</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</td> 

<td colspan="25">
<h2>Cell title 25%</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</td> 
</tr>

<tr class="scale">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks but the solution is not the one I was looking for .. and responsive layout is very complicated to adapt.

Comment: Are you sure the solution above is not responsive? I've just looked at it on my mobile - it looks completely responsive. Can you indicate what you feel ought to be included but isn't? Thanks.

Comment: The code i posted is "div" based. In mobile view your solution is adaptive but not responsive. The last row with 100 cells is a good idea but I would prefer a solution with smallest possible code. P.S. excuse my English, I use google translate..
Thanks for you time